# Question related to Equipotential Surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential

How will you show that *equipotential* surface is always directed **perpendicular** to *electric* field?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple. Consider $V$ the electric potential, then an equipotential surface is simply a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $V(x,y,z)=c$ where $c$ is some constant. In that case, consider $S(c)$ the equipotential surface defined like that. Consider $\gamma : (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)\to S(c)$ a path in that surface. Consider also the electric field $E$ at the surface measured at $\gamma(t)$ (a point in the path), then the dot product between the electric field and the tangent vector to the path is

$$E(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t) = -\nabla V(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t)$$

and by the chain rule this means that this product is $-(V\circ\gamma)'(t)$ and this of course must be zero, because $V\circ \gamma$ is a constant function since $\gamma$ maps into $S(c)$ on which the potential is constant.

Because of that:

$$E(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t) = 0$$

and so $E$ must be orthogonal to each equipotential surface. Notice also that it's not restricted to electric fields. For any real valued function $f$, the gradient $\nabla f$ is orthogonal to the level sets.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to prove through contradiction.

> let us assume that **E** is not perpendicular to the equipotential surface and make angle $\theta$ with the area vector **A** of the equipotential surface .
>   [image]
>   Then we find that Electric field has a component **$Esin\theta$ along the 
>   surface**.

Since this is an equipotential surface,it is supposed to not have any potential difference on its surface.
And this would not be possible if E has a component along the surface.

[If **E** has a component along the surface.Non zero Work has to be done against the electric field to move a test charge on  the surface which implies that potential will not be same all over the surface]

Therefore,$Esin\theta$ **must be zero** so as to satisfy the defination of the equipotential surface.

$Esin\theta=0$ only when $\theta=0 or 180$ degrees. i.e parallel to area vector and normal to the surface)